# My input-file dialong doesn't opens? HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've been working on a site for homework, and i tried to make some buttons some of them are for submitting others like this to attach a file, im talking about the input type "file" , well the problem is that when i press it, it doesn't happen nothing just the colour changes because it has a hover function. How i can fix it?
HTML

```
<div class=radioB>

                <input class=inputfile type="file" name=file>
                <label for="file" id=inputlabel><img src="style/iconos/attachment.png" width="30px"></label>

            </div>
```

CSS

```
 .inputfile{
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;



}
.inputfile + #inputlabel {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;



}
.inputfile:focus + #inputlabel,
.inputfile + #inputlabel:hover {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    border-radius: 510px;

}
.inputfile + #inputlabel {
    cursor: pointer; /* "hand" cursor */
}
#inputlabel img{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;  

}
.radioB #inputlabel{
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 6px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: darkslategray;
    border-radius: 510px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You use on label `for="file"` attribute BUT your `input` has no ID `file`... It should be `<input class=inputfile type="file" name="file" id="file">`

Comment: "<input class=inputfile type="file" id="file" name=file>" should work.

Comment: I don't think OP is talking about any jQuery solution. This can be achieved by pure css. The input dialogue is not opening because it is behind the image.

Answer (score 0):

Add id attribute for img and input tags then use this script

```
<div class=radioB>
   <input class=inputfile type="file" name=file id=b>
   <label for="file" id=inputlabel><img src="style/iconos/attachment.png" width="30px" id=a></label>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#a").on("click", function() {
        $("#b").trigger("click");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: it worked! thank you! i was gettting tired of looking and searching the fix!